# assign a pointer to a pointer in assembly and c

Tags: c, assembly, x86

In a C method, given the only local variable int i (uninitialized), that i'd like to store in the register %ecx, and given the following struct located in %ebp+8:

```
typedef struct {
  char c;
  int k;
  int *m;
} S1;
```

how do I translate into assembly (at&t syntax) the following code:

```
i=*(a.m);
i=i+a.k;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Compile with the `-S` flag and look at the generated assembly.

Comment: Type of `i` variable is unknown

Answer (score 0):

Given that i is int, in masm it's going to be something like:

```
;i = *(a.m);
mov eax, [ebp+13]  ; 13 = +8+1+4
mov ecx, [eax]     ; store i in ecx

;i = i + a.k;
mov eax, ptr [ebp+9]  ; 9 = +8+1
add ecx, eax          ; new value of i
```

Comment: `13` isn't `13h` and the naive offsets are wrong anyway, because C aligns struct members. As such, `m` is going to be at `ebp+16` and `k` at `ebp+12`. Also,you can do the addition using a memory operand.

Comment: I agree, but we don't know the constraints. Alignment can be changed with parameters or pragmas. `13h` is a good catch. I'll fix

Comment: It can be changed, but that would be the exception and should have been mentioned in the question. Otherwise, assume defaults.